# Vue 3 emit as v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some difficulties with integrating component that is custom dropdown select.
So idea is to get data with v-model from parent component, but I have no idea how to pass that emit. So what is it exactly.

This is my parent component, where I'm caling selector.

```
<DropdownSelect :items="items"/>
```

as you see I'm passing array of objects and child component is foreaching them and doing the thing, but how could I call v-model and get data that is selected in child component?

In child component I have function onClick and I have that selected object, and it looks like:

```
emit('selected', get);
```

So how could I easily do something like:

```
<DropdownSelect :items="items" v-model="something" />
```

but without emit? I could do something like:

```
<DropdownSelect :items="items" @selected="object_here"/>
```

but I need it to be in v-model, is that possible?

Comment: Have you gone through these docs, I think this is exactly what you are looking for: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html#using-v-bind-sync

Answer (score 0):

from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-add-v-model-support:

> To understand how to implement v-model support in your components, you need to understand how it works under the hood. The v-model="prop" value is shorthand for :value="prop" @input="prop = arguments[0]".

v-model listens to 'input' emit event to fire,

Try using:
`this.$emit('input', data);`
in your component.

Comment: Unless the OP is using the Objects API, this answer is not applicable.